# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" from UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, selector

I know this question has been asked many times. But I can't seem to get past this error. I had it working in a previous version of my app using Objective C.

Both the methods below are within the same `UIViewController`.

The view controller is also held as a reference by the root view controller, part of a `UINavigationController`.

```
func loadEditView(sender: AnyObject, animated: Bool = true) {
    var editViewController: EditViewController = EditViewController()
    // set some stuff up
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(editViewController, animated: animated)
}

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    var button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Edit, target: self, action: Selector("loadEditView:"))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
}
```

The error message is

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyApp.ScaleViewController loadEditView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d643d0'
```

Comment: Update your question with the compete and exact error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You setup your bar button item with the selector `loadEditView:`. Not that the name indicates it takes one parameter.

However, your actual `loadEditView` function takes two parameters. Hence the error.

You need to change your `loadEditView` method to only take one parameter - the sender. There is no way to have the button handler also take the 2nd `animated` parameter.

Comment: that was it thanks. reason for the second parameter is so it can be called by another controller without animation. guess I'll just need to split it out into two methods.